# Could not convert negative string to a float

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

```py
def net_value(count, wait):  
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='additional_percent_value']")))
    time.sleep(1)  
    net_profit = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("additional_percent_value")[0].text.split(" %")  
    net_profitfl = float(net_profit[0])

    if net_profitfl > 0.0:
        net_value = float(net_profit[0])
        profits.update({count: net_value})
        positive_color = {count: net_value}
        print(colored(f'{positive_color}', 'green'))
        return net_value
```

Code runs fine with positive numbers inside strings, but with negatives gives me this error:

```
{2: 8.59} {3: 3.01} {4: 7.3} {5: 6.83} {6: 1.52} {7: 0.25} {8: 0.25}  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
net_profitfl = float(net_profit[0])  
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '−1.54'
```

I tried with `list(map(float, net_profitstr[0]))` and `np.array` instead of a direct float but it gave me the same error

Comment: Can't reproduce. `float('-1.54')` works. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DeepSpace: Try it on `float('−1.54')` (the value shown in the exception message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the first character is not an ASCII minus sign but the Unicode version. Therefore change:

```
net_profitfl = float(net_profit[0])
```

...to...

```
net_profitfl = float(net_profit[0].replace('\u2212', '-'))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Tnx :)